# Extrema and inflection points of the function $y = \cos^2(x) - \cos(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Please help me find the extrema and inflection points of the function $y = \cos^2(x) - \cos(x)$.

So far: $$y'=-2 \cos(x)\sin(x)+\sin(x)$$ $$y'' = 2\sin^2(x) - 2\cos^2(x) + \cos(x)$$

$y' = 0$ when $x = 0, \pi, \pi/3, 5\pi/3$

I plugged these values into $y''$ to find min/max which are as follows:

$x = 0, \pi$ : MAX

$x =  \pi/3$, $5\pi/3$ : MIN

The issue I have is finding the inflection points, i used the quadratic formula to solve for $\cos(x)$ by converting (via trig ID's) $y'' = 2\sin^2(x) + 2\cos^2(x) + \cos(x)$ to $y'' = -2\cos^2(x) + \cos(x) = 0$ which gave me $\cos(x) = 0, 1/2$, and $x = \pi/2, 3\pi/2, \pi/3, 5\pi/3$

The solution shows that the inflection points are at $x = 32$ deg $32', 126$ deg $23', 233$ deg $37'$, and $327$ deg $28' $

Can you please help by showing how these inflection points were solved for? Where did I make my mistake? I have no idea how they got those degrees.

Answer (score 1):

You changed from addition to subtraction of the first two terms in $y''$:

Recall that $$y'' = 2sin^2(x) - 2cos^2(x) + cos(x)$$

$$y'' = 2(1-\cos^2 x) - 2 \cos^2(x) + \cos x \\
= -4\cos^2 x + \cos x + 2 \iff 4\cos^2 x - \cos x - 2$$

Try solving for $\cos x$ now, since we have a quadratic in $\cos x$. I suggest using the quadratic formula: $\cos x = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{33}}{8}$. You can get an approximation by using $\cos^{-1}(\cos(x))$ for each of the two solutions for $\cos x$.

Comment: hi, thanks for your quick response, i can't seem to get cos(x) = -1/2, i get: (-1 +/- sqrt(33))/-8, can u show that step please ? also, i don't see how your answers in radians equal the solutions answers in degrees, can you also explain that please. thanks

Comment: Yes, which turns out to be equivalent to my solution above. If you use a calculator and want the solution in degrees, be sure it is in "degree" mode.

Comment: ok, so i see that my two cos(x) values: 0.843, -0.593, in DEGREE mode equate to the 32deg and 126deg values of the solution, however, i am still uncertain about the other two values, where do we solve for those two, given the quadratic only outputted two values of cos(x) ? thanks for your replies

Comment: Note that $\cos(0.843\,\text{ radians})\approx \cos (32^\circ) = \cos(360^\circ - 32^\circ) = \cos(328^\circ)$ and $\cos(-0.593\,\text{ radians}) \approx \cos (126^\circ) = \cos(180^\circ - 54^\circ)  = \cos(180^\circ + 54^\circ) = \cos (234^\circ)$